# datepicker - Highcharts Gauge Json

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts, datepicker

I am trying to get JSON from an onSelect function of a Jquery datePicker and send it to a highchairs gauge. this is my [website](http://alanmarine.000a.biz/webMonitor1.php) that shows what I am trying to accomplish.

I cannot figure out why it will not display the correct data in the Highcharts gauges.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate: new Date(2016, 07 - 1, 1), maxDate: 0, dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', onSelect: function(dateText, data) {
        var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
        $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
        $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",   
        url: "clickdates.php",                  
        data: {choice: dateText}, 
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function(json_data) { 
          console.log(json_data)
        $('#apDiv2a').html(json_data.ampPowerP[0]).show();
        $('#apDiv2b').html(json_data.dayPowerP[0]).show(); 
        $('#apDiv6a').html(json_data.monthAmpP[0]).show();
        $('#apDiv6b').html(json_data.monthPowerP[0]).show(); 
        $('#apDiv8a').html(json_data.yearAmpP[0]).show();    
        $('#apDiv8b').html(json_data.yearPowerP[0]).show();
        $('#neon1').html(json_data.stateC[0]).show();
        $('#alarm').html(json_data.alarm[0]).show();
        $('#fault').html(json_data.fault[0]).show();

      } 
    }) 
    $(function () {
    var options = {
chart: {
    type: 'gauge',          
    renderTo: 'minVolt',
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBackgroundImage: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,          
    backgroundColor: null,      
    borderWidth: 0,

        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0,
        spacingBottom: 0,


},

title: {
    text: null
},

pane: {
    startAngle: -150,
    endAngle: 150,
    background: [{
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, '#FFF'],
                [1, '#333']
            ]
        },
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '109%'
    }, {
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, '#333'],
                [1, '#FFF']
            ]
        },
        borderWidth: 1,
        outerRadius: '107%'
    }, {
        // default background
    }, {
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        borderWidth: 0,
        outerRadius: '105%',
        innerRadius: '103%'
    }]
},

// the value axis
yAxis: {
    min: 20,
    max: 40,

    minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    minorTickWidth: 1,
    minorTickLength: 10,
    minorTickPosition: 'inside',
    minorTickColor: '#666',

    tickPixelInterval: 20,
    tickWidth: 2,
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    tickLength: 10,
    tickColor: '#666',
    labels: {
        step: 2,
        rotation: 'auto'
    },
    title: {
        y: 20,
        text: 'Volts'
    },
    plotBands: [{
        from: 20,
        to: 22,
        color: '#DF5353' // red
    }, {
        from: 22,
        to: 23,
        color: '#FFFF00' // yellow
    }, {
        from: 23,
        to: 30,
        color: '#55BF3B' // green
    }, {
        from: 30,
        to: 40,
        color: '#DF5353' // red
    }]
},       credits: {
     enabled:false,
},

series: [{
    name: 'gauge1',
     data: [],
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
},
}]    
}; 
   $.ajax({
    url: "clickdates.php",
    data: {choice: data}, 
    type:'get',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,

    success: function(data){
        options.series[0].data = data.gauge1;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
    }
});
}); 

}});

});
```

This is the PHP for the gauge that outputs {"gauge1":[24.2]}

```
$choice = isset($_POST['choice']) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 

$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","ENERGY");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: "  . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(Vb_min_daily),'24.6') AS choice FROM Solar WHERE date = '".$choice."'"; 
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$battMin = array( $row['choice']);

$outarr['gauge1'] = $battMin;
print json_encode($outarr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a computer programmer by trade. Just a simple DIY type of individual trying to Do Thing Myself...

I found my error.

It was in the PHP that relates to the JSON. I was using $_POST when I should have been using $_GET

Here is what I had...

```
$choice = isset($_POST['choice']) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d");
```

When it should have be...

```
$choice = isset($_GET['choice']) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_GET['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d");
```

A simple change of POST to GET, and everything works.

The weeks of frustration, and then when things finally work... What a great feeling, and a lesson well leaned from just falling on my face, and reading more with stronger determination from each failure. So wonderful.

Alan